# Inserting Data into Two Tables in one Query

Tags: sql

Student Table

```
id|student_num|name|surname
```

Course Table

```
id|course_name
```

Student_course Table

```
course_id|student_id|mark
```

When I insert data into the Student Table (id, student_num, name, surname), the id should be inserted into Student_course Table, student_id column.

Comment: This isn't a question, it's just a statement of work.

Comment: How are you *currently* inserting data into these tables, and in what way is that attempt not working or not sufficient?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? it does not make sense to me

Comment: Hint: you actually need 2 SQL queries. SQL only supports inserting in one table per an `INSERT` statement. Multiple coordinated inserts just run in the same transaction.

Comment: @9000: In Postgres you could do that in a single statement.

Comment: Which course_id should be inserted into the `student_course` table?

Comment: @9000: see my answer. That's a single statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ha, a nice CSE trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to insert the new student for **all** courses, then in Postgres you can do this:

```
with new_student as (
  insert into student 
    (id, student_num, name, surname)
  values 
    (1, 42, 'Dent', 'Arthur)
  returning id
)
insert into Student_course (student_id, course_id)
select (select id from new_student), 
       id
from course;
```

Comment: @David I have an INSERT query for each table. I was wondering if you can insert data into two tables with one query.

Comment: @ApheleleKubeka: that **is** one query.